# Spring AOP execution expression with two arguments

Tags: spring-boot, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I want to advice the following method

```
public BaseRepresentationObject createLedgerTransaction(Long fromUserId, Long toUserId, Double serviceAmount,
        Double masaryCommission, Double merchantCommission, Double appliedFees, Double tax, Long ratePlanId,
        Long serviceId, String pendingTrx, String globalTrxId)
```

and extract the two arguments : `pendingTrx`, `globalTrxId` to be used in the advice method.

I use the following execution expression:

```
@Around("execution(* com.masary.ledger.service.components.LedgerTransactionComponent.createLedgerTransaction(..)) && args(pendingTrx,globalTrxId,..)")
    public Object doBasicProfilingLedgerCreate(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp , String pendingTrx, String globalTrxId) throws Throwable
```

The application is built successfully, but the advice code is not executed.

I use Spring boot with `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)` on my configuration class.

By the way I have  `@AfterThrowing` advice to run correctly. So I highly think that the problem is with my execution expression.

**Update:**
I have very weird finding : when I use any argument of type String the advice does not work, otherwise(Long or Double) it works.

any explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, using `@Around`:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {
    @Around("execution (* com.masary.ledger.service.components.LedgerTransactionComponent.createLedgerTransaction(..)) && args(.., pendingTrx, globalTrxId)")
    public Object aroundCreateLedgerTransaction(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, String pendingTrx, String globalTrxId) throws Throwable{
        System.out.println("it works!");
        return pjp.proceed();
    }
}
```

Or `@Around` with a `@Pointcut`:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution (* com.masary.ledger.service.components.LedgerTransactionComponent.createLedgerTransaction(..))")
    public void pointcutCreateLedgerTransaction(){}

    @Around("pointcutCreateLedgerTransaction() && args(.., pendingTrx, globalTrxId)")
    public Object aroundCreateLedgerTransaction(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, String pendingTrx, String globalTrxId) throws Throwable{
        System.out.println("it works!");
        return pjp.proceed();
    }
}
```

I *think* your error is the order of your args:

- you specified: `args(pendingTrx,globalTrxId,..)`
- and it should be `args(.., pendingTrx,globalTrxId)`

Comment: thanks a million...do you have any document for the expression language of the method arguments in AOP, because I have still similar problems.

Comment: I used this as reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

Comment: In my case not adding the arguments to the definition of the pointcut results in the following exception:error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut 
 at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:319) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar:na]